# Embed dylib in Xamarin.Mac binding dll

Tags: dylib, monomac, xamarin.mac

I'm creating bindings for `Xamarin.Mac` / `MonoMac`. I'd like to embed the `dylib` in the generated `dll` like it's done on `Xamarin.iOS` with the `[LinkWith]` attribute.

Is it possible to do that ? if so how ? Or should I load the `dylib` from the consuming application ? again in this case, how ?

I tried:
- dropping the `dylib` in the **Native References** folder (doesn't work)
- adding a `[assembly: MonoMac.RequiredFramework]` attribute (doesn't find the `dylib`)

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I have a .dylib, or a handful of .a that I would like to include in my XamMac project. Adding to the Native References folder seems to do absolutely nothing...

Comment: @migueldeicaza once said "we're working on it"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to load the `.dylib` from the consuming application by doing the following:

- Add the `.dylib` to your project as **Content**
- add the `RequiredFrameworkAttribute`:

```cs
    [assembly: MonoMac.RequiredFramework("mylib.dylib")]
```

- register the assembly from the `AppDelegate` constructor:

```cs
    public partial class AppDelegate : NSApplicationDelegate
    {
        public AppDelegate ()
        {
            Type t = typeof(ATypeFromTheAssembly);
            MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.RegisterAssembly (t.Assembly);
        }
    }
```

That still doesn't embed the `.dylib` in the bindings assembly, but it qualifies as progress

Comment: I've been trying to get libz.dylib to get included - but I think the problem is that libz is Fat (has both i386 and x86_64).